# Rounding x-Axis label in chartkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chartkick

I am using `chartkick` to display a line chart of how many orders where processed per hour of the current day. As I am using Postgres, the code looks like this:

```
line_chart Order.group("DATE_PART('hour', creation_date)").order("extract (hour from creation_date) ASC").count, curve: false, label: "Orders"
```

This is working, except that the x-Axis label is formatted like this:

[image]

Is there a way to have it formatted like this: `01:00`?

Comment: sql would be `substr(creation_date::time(0)::text,1,5)` instead of `DATE_PART('hour', creation_date)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
line_chart Order.group("DATE_PART('hour', creation_date)").order("extract (hour from creation_date) ASC").count, curve: false, label: "Orders", {library: {hAxis: {title: "Time", format: 'hh:mm'}}
```

Hope this will work

Comment: Unfortunately, this only adds the title to the axis